# @OneToOne relationship with additional constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

Suppose, we have two entities, first one:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entitya")
public class EntityA {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private Long name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<EntityB> childEntities;

}
```

and the second:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityb")
public class EntityB {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "master")
  private Boolean master;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
  private EntityA parent;

}
```

So far, so good. However underlying database tables and constrains enforce that for any `entityA` there can be only one `EntityB` with boolean field `master` set to true. I can extract it by adding following method to entityA:

```
public entityB getMasterChild() {

  for(entityB ent : childEntities) {
    if(ent.isMaster()) {
      return ent;
    }
  }

}
```

The question is, can I create `@OneToOne` relationship in `EntityA` that can express that rule, so that `entityA` can have additional `masterChild` member of type entityB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to create/define a relationship between two entities based on a value of some entity's property. The think is that relationship between entities is defined on entities count (how many entities can has the other entity) and not on some entity's property value.

However
If you really want to use `@OneToOne` mapping for `masterChild` I would recommend creating a separate table/entity for it. Once this is done, you can include this new `MasterChild` entity into `EntityA` and annotate it with `@OneToOne`.

Here is new MasterChild entity

```
@Entity
public class MasterChild extends EntityB{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;    
}
```

Note that I have removed 'master' from EntityB as it is no longer needed

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entityb")
public class EntityB {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
  private EntityA parent;

}
```

And here is modified EntityA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entitya")
public class EntityA {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private Long name;

  @OneToOne
  private MasterChild master;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<EntityB> childEntities;

}
```

Comment: I really dislike such redudancy, but I guess this is the price you pay for using ORM package